# jq: how to replace keys with values ​from other keys whose ​are in strings of some array

Tags: json, jq

Consider following array:

```json
{
"A": 100, 
"B": 200, 
"C": "ccc",
"arr": [
  {
    "result": ".R1.R3", 
    "fmt": "%s::%s::baz", 
    "vals": [".A", ".B"]
  },
  {
    "result": ".R2.R4", 
    "fmt": "%s/%s", 
    "vals": [".A", ".C"]
  }
]
}
```

I need to replace keys according some format with values ​​from other keys whose ​​are in strings of some array.

Desired output:

```json
{
"A": 100, 
"B": 200, 
"C": "ccc",
"R1": {"R3": "100::200::baz"},
"R2": {"R4": "100/ccc"}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify what language you use in the `.vals` array items to reference into the document. If you were trying to execute (arbitrary) `jq` code from there, know that `jq` cannot do that with code provided as a string value. `jq` also doesn't provide `printf`-style substitutions using `%s` (and others). Therefore, you either need to re-implement a whole bunch of (third-party) functionality, or revert to a simpler scheme describing your references and substitutions.

For the sake of simplicity, this solution just removes the first character (the dot) from the `.vals` array items and treats the result as top-level field name, and then simply replaces each occurrence of a literal `%s` with the next value. This should give you an overview of the general technique.

```bash
. as $top | reduce .arr[] as $a (del(.arr); .[$a.result] = (
  reduce $a.vals[][1:] as $val ($a.fmt; sub("%s"; $top[$val] | @text))
))
```

```json
{
  "A": 100,
  "B": 200,
  "C": "ccc",
  ".R1": "100::200::baz",
  ".R2": "100/ccc"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/A3nbfVokiuW)

---

One quite simple way of improving the reference language is to instead use path expressions `jq` provides functions for. They are represented as arrays with field names as strings items and array indices as number items. `.A` would become `["A"]`, `.A[3].B` would become `["A",3,"B"]`, and so on. Thus, assume your input looked like this:

```json
{
  "A": 100,
  "B": 200,
  "C": "ccc",
  "arr": [
    {
      "result": ".R1",
      "fmt": "%s::%s::baz",
      "vals": [["A"], ["B"]]
    },
    {
      "result": ".R2",
      "fmt": "%s/%s",
      "vals": [["A"], ["C"]]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you could use `getpath` to evaluate the given path expressions as above:

```bash
. as $top | reduce .arr[] as $a (del(.arr); .[$a.result] = (
  reduce $a.vals[] as $path ($a.fmt; sub("%s"; $top | getpath($path) | @text))
))
```

```json
{
  "A": 100,
  "B": 200,
  "C": "ccc",
  ".R1": "100::200::baz",
  ".R2": "100/ccc"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/0B7Nb2OHuZA)

---

Edit: As the question has been modified with the `.result` value now also being subject to reference interpretation, measures taken for `.vals` therefore apply to it as well. This implies changing the suggested source document format to use path expressions as in `"result": ["R1", "R3"]`, and changing the assignment in the suggested code from `.[$a.result] = ...` to `setpath($a.result; ...)`:

```json
{
  "A": 100,
  "B": 200,
  "C": "ccc",
  "arr": [
    {
      "result": ["R1", "R3"],
      "fmt": "%s::%s::baz",
      "vals": [["A"], ["B"]]
    },
    {
      "result": ["R2", "R4"],
      "fmt": "%s/%s",
      "vals": [["A"], ["C"]]
    }
  ]
}
```

```bash
. as $top | reduce .arr[] as $a (del(.arr); setpath($a.result;
  reduce $a.vals[] as $path ($a.fmt; sub("%s"; $top | getpath($path) | @text))
))
```

```json
{
  "A": 100,
  "B": 200,
  "C": "ccc",
  "R1": {
    "R3": "100::200::baz"
  },
  "R2": {
    "R4": "100/ccc"
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/3Too41ur_qX)

Comment: Every item in .vals is just string containing path to key in original json document. I used jq notation in my example. But maybe it is better to use another notation.

Comment: I had a mistake in my Desired output section. I fixed it. Key "result" of "arr" should be interpreted as path in original JSON document.

Comment: .[$a.result] = (...) change to setpath($a.result; (....)). And use the same notation for result as for vals: arrays with field names as strings items.

Comment: @AntonRomanov With `.result` also being subject to reference interpretation, everything said for `.vals` applies here as well:  `jq` code cannot be interpreted; rethink the reference language; suggested use of path expressions. The latter would imply encoding them as array, e.g. `"result": ["R1", "R3"]`, and changing the assignment code from `.[$a.result] = ...` to `setpath($a.result; ...)`. [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/3Too41ur_qX)